# Helm template arithmetic division

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Anyone tried to make an arithmetic division in [Helm](https://helm.sh/)?

According to [sprig/Math Functions](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/math.html), the following should work:

```
{{ .Values.myvalue | div 2 }}
```

However, the result is wrong. e.g. `6/2 = 0`, `4/2 = 0`, `1/2 = 2`.

Any hint ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You use the function the wrong way:
See function [declaration](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/blob/bf29da0d74f74aeb5c3e3e7207eab76c28ac4049/functions.go#L182).

Your template should be:

```
{{ div .Values.myvalue 2 }}
```